# raku What is a better way to do rotor from the end?

Tags: list, raku, rotor

If data at the end of a list are more important, and I want :partial list to be left at the beginning of the list while preserving the initial order, I do this:

```
> my @a = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
> say @a.rotor(4, :partial)
((0 1 2 3) (4 5 6 7) (8 9)) # not what I want; important data at end gets cut off;
> say @a.reverse.rotor(4, :partial).reverse.map({$_.reverse});
((0 1) (2 3 4 5) (6 7 8 9)) # this is what I want
```

Is there a way to avoid the 3 "reverse" operations? Is it possible to add a :fromEnd adverb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my @a = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
my @b = @a.rotor(4, :partial)».elems.reverse;
say @a.rotor(|@b);
```

Comment: Thank you very much chenyf ! I like your one-liner: say @a.rotor(|(@a.rotor(4, :partial)».elems.reverse));

Answer (score 6):

You can use `@a.rotor(2,4,4)` or a little more universal `@a.rotor(@a
% 4,slip 4 xx *)`. Of course, you could define function

```
multi batch ( $_, $n, :from-end($)! ) {
    .rotor: .elems % $n, slip $n xx *
}
say batch  ^10,  4,:from-end; #or even
say (^10).&batch(4):from-end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much wamba !

Answer (score 3):

Taking the last question first: Yes, it is possible, but it would probably be called `:end` for consistency, and no I don't think it is likely to be added.  But then I could be wrong :-)

I'm not sure how golfed your example is, but if you're really working from an array, why not stuff it first with values to make it evenly divisible by 4, and then remove them afterwards again:

```
my @a = ^10;
@a.splice(0,0, Any xx @a % 4);
say @a.batch(4);  # (((Any) (Any) 0 1) (2 3 4 5) (6 7 8 9))
```

Note I've used the shorter `^10` (which is a range from `0` to `10`, excluding the endpoint).  And I've used the simpler `batch` method, as we are sure there won't be any partial lists.  In any case, no `reverse` is needed, just checking values afterwards.

Mind you, the `reverse` method on an array, is relatively cheap, as it does not actually move any values.

Comment: Thank you very much Elizabeth Mattijsen !

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the number of elements left in the `:partial` list.

```raku
@a.elems % 4
```

Then combine it with a repeating sequence of the size you wanted.

```raku
4 xx *
```

If you tried to combine them simply it won't work

```raku
@a.elems % 4, 4 xx *
```

That is because the above is a list of two elements. The first is the result of the modulus operation, and the second is an infinite sequence.

You can just use `flat` to make them a single sequence.

```raku
flat @a.elems % 4, 4 xx *
```

Here is the resulting code.

```raku
@a.rotor( flat @a.elems % 4, 4 xx * )
```

Comment: Thank you very much Brad Gilbert !!